# dotnet cli test command packages argument

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there is a mechanism of passing the custom package cache directory to the .NET Core CLI when running the `test` command?

For `build` I can do:

```
dotnet build project.csproj --packages c:\custompackagefolder
```

But `test` says the `--packages` argument is not valid and goes to the global package cache instead.

This is on Dot Net Core 3.1.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain you can provide a feed on the `dotnet build` command, but you should be able to handle this with two commands.

Perform a [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) and specify a feed using the `--packages` parameter, and then do a [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) with `--no-restore` switch.

Comment: an alternative for the restore would be to use `dotnet restore -s c:\custompackagefolder`, but I think that should really be posed as a different answer. potentially a better, comprehensive one.